# Plot Vector according to vector values

Tags: r, plot

I have a Matrix of 200k*2, the first vector has values, the 2nd has either -1 or +1.
I would like to plot the first vector as Blue points when the 2nd value is +1 and Red points when the 2nd value is -1.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
## Create some data
## set.seed(1) ## To make the plot reproducible
dat <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000), b = sample(c(-1,1), 1000, TRUE))
## Plot the first column dat$a,
## color blue if dat$b == -1 and red otherwise
plot(dat$a, col = ifelse(dat$b == -1, "blue", "red"))
```

[image]

And with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = seq(a), y = a, col = factor(b))) + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

And with ggvis

```
library(ggvis)
dat$color <- c("blue", "red")[factor(dat$b)]
dat %>% ggvis(~seq(a), ~a, fill := ~color)
```

[image]